# How do I change a string to a python type

Tags: python, types

If I have a string which is the same as a python data type and I would like to check if another variable is that type how would I do it? Example below.

```
dtype = 'str'
x = 'hello'
bool = type(x) == dtype
```

The above obviously returns False but I'd like to check that type('hello') is a string.

Comment: What counts as "a Python data type"? Do you care about user-defined classes, for example?

Comment: If you have a set number of types, why not just create an explicit mapping?

Answer (score 1):

You can use `eval`:

```
bool = type(x) is eval(dtype)
```

but beware, `eval` will execute any python code, so if you're taking `dtype` as user input, they can execute their own code in this line.

Answer (score 1):

### Don't write :

```
bool = type(x) == dtype
```

*because `dtype` is a variabe It is in the form of a string , not logical !!*

*you should be entered a statement to check is str or no*

Also, the string in Python is an object so to call it write :
`str` not write `dtype = 'str'`,exemple :

```
type(x) == str
```

### i fixed your code and just try this :

```
x = 'hello'
if type(x) == str:
    print(True)
else:
    print(False)
```

***It's a simple code but there are other shortcuts that come from Python***

> try that and good day for coding !!

Answer (score 0):

If your code *actually* looks like the example you showed and `dtype` isn't coming from user input, then also keep in mind that `str` (as a value in Python) is a valid object which represents the string type. Consider

```
dtype = str
x = 'hello'
print(isinstance(x, dtype))
```

`str` is a value like any other and can be assigned to variables. No `eval` magic required.

Comment: dtype is being read in from a csv so I don't have control over the variable in that way

Answer (score 0):

I think the best way to do this verification is to use **isinstance**, like:

```
isinstance(x, str) # returns True
```

From the docs:

> 

isinstance(object, classinfo)

```
Return True if the object argument is an instance of the classinfo argument, or of a (direct, indirect or virtual) subclass thereof. If object is not an object of the given type, the function always returns False. If classinfo is a tuple of type objects (or recursively, other such tuples), return True if object is an instance of any of the types. If classinfo is not a type or tuple of types and such tuples, a TypeError exception is raised.
```

https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#isinstance